# Java Genericity with '?'

Tags: java, generics

I try to open and read a file whith genericity, but I can't store the result of my search into my arrayList because I can't create a temp Object with the '?' type.
The error appears here "Object temp=(Object)entree.readObject();
                        liste.add(temp);"

```
private void open(ArrayList<?> liste){
    JFileChooser choixFichier = new JFileChooser();
    int resultat=choixFichier.showOpenDialog(null);
    if(resultat==JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "création du fichier annulée");
        return;
    }
    File nomFichier=choixFichier.getSelectedFile();
    if(nomFichier==null || nomFichier.getName().equals(""))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"nom du fichier incorrect");
    }
    ObjectInputStream entree = null; 
    try{ 
        entree = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(nomFichier)); 
        while(true){
            Object temp=(Object)entree.readObject();
            liste.add(temp);
        } 
    }
    catch(java.io.EOFException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Fin de de la lecture");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
    finally{
        try{
            entree.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to cast in list.add "liste.add(temp);" will be more like "liste.add((TypeOfList)temp);"  Please provide how your "liste" is defined.

Comment: do you need to cast to Object?  what happens if you remove the cast (Object)

Comment: @DanArmstrong I defined my liste like this "private void open(ArrayList<?> liste)"

Comment: You cannot add to a list defined as <?>  You'll need to make it ArrayList<Object> or something more specific.

Comment: @DanArmstrong If I do something more specific I lose my genericity.

Comment: @DanArmstrong I've try to define my fuction by replacing <?> with <Object> but when I call it in my main code it doesn't work. I really need to find a to define an object whith '?' type

Comment: @DanArmstrong I'm sorry, your solution works perfectly, thank you. I had just forgoten to modify the declaration of my function.

Comment: What does your main method look like?

Comment: @MCEmperor My main method is too voluminous, I can't put it here but my problem has been solved

Comment: @A.JO If it was needed to answer the question, you should then remove the parts not related to the problem from your main method. But now when it's solved, you should mark the appropriate answer as accepted.

Answer (score -1):

Now that we know a bit more.  If you need a specific type:

```
private <E> void open(ArrayList<E> liste) {
    ...
    liste.add((E)temp); // Compiler will warn, but this is the way
    ...
}
```

This will case the "temp" object to a type matching the generic bounds of "liste".  If you give it a list of Integer, it will cast to Integer.  However, due to "reification", this is not well enforced at runtime and hence a warning.

If you want stronger runtime checks:

```
private <E> void open(ArrayList<? super E> liste, Class<E> clazz) {
    ...
    liste.add(clazz.cast(temp)); // No compiler warnings and runtime enforcment
    ...
}
```

Or if you just need ArrayList:

```
private void open(ArrayList<Object> liste) {
    ...
    liste.add(temp);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason you cannot add an `Object` to an `ArrayList<?>`, is because an `ArrayList<?>` is a list containing objects of a specific, unknown type. Note that it is not exactly the same as if I said *"objects of any type"*. That means it *could* be, for instance, an `ArrayList<String>`. And you just cannot add an `Object` to a list of `String`s. That's why `liste.add(temp)` didn't work.

If you want to specify the types of the objects read, then you need to specify the type in your method signature:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private <T> void open(ArrayList<T> liste) {
    ...
    liste.add((T) temp);
```